# Sorting criteria for ordering this words?

Tags: c++, string, sorting

I want to do two types of sorting, the first one is as follow:

Given a set of distinct lines with two words separate with a space, order them in a way that the next line has a first word equal to the last word of the previous line. For example:

- Pamela Luisa
- Luis Angel
- Pedro Luis
- Luisa Elianny
- Angel Pedro
- Elianny Pamela

Should give something like:

- Luisa Elianny
- Elianny Pamela
- Pamela Luisa
- Pedro Luis
- Luis Angel
- Angel Pedro

I read every line as a string, put it inside a vector and used a sort comparison function like this:

```
bool cmp(std::string a, std::string b)
{
    std::string prb = a.substr(a.find(" ")+1),
                prb2 = b.substr(0, b.find(" "));

    return prb == prb2;
}
```

But to get the desire result I have to sort twice. I don't understand why exactly that happens.

The second ordering criteria is:

Given a set of words order then so that the next word has the same first letter as the last letter of the previous word. For example:

- EO
- UIU
- AEIOU

Should give something like:

- AEIOU
- UIU
- EO

I did something like this, but doesn't seems to work properly.

```
bool cmp(std::string a, std::string b)
{
    if(b[b.size()-1] == a[0] && a[0] != b[0]) return false;
    return b[b.size()-1] == a[0];
}
```

How can I make this two sorting works fine?

Comment: You need to ask your teacher for some clarification, because I haven't a clue what he's asking for.

Comment: What is the exact result that is expected?

Comment: It's not an assignment. I just can't figure it out. What parts didn't you understand? @remyabel I gave some examples, can you specified what is wrong?

Comment: Are you passing this function to `std::sort`? Because that (or any other general sorting algorithm) is not an appropriate vehicle for this kind of "sorting". `std::sort` needs to be able to look at *any* two elements in the range, and determine if and which one comes first.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley That's exactly what I'm doing :P What approach should I take then?

Comment: #1 is not a sorting problem (for one thing, you can reorder the first three lines and the last three lines, and still satisfy the requirements). You want an algorithm for finding cycles in a graph. Google for that.

Comment: @0aps Why isn't "Angel Pedro" above "Pedro Luis" for example? Is there the potential to have multiple answers?

Comment: @remyabel Yes, that can happens.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: #1 is (or at least can be viewed as) a sorting problem--specifically, a topological sort, though, for what it's worth, a topological sort will also find cycles (and fail if it finds any).

Comment: @JerryCoffin I don't think so. What's the comparison predicate, one that's transitive?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Sounds to me like you don't know what "topological sort" is/means. Hint: in C++ you'd probably use something like Boost Graph Library (not `std::sort`) to do a topological sort.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Yes you are right. Upon closer consideration, it can be stated as a topological sort. Cycles can be dealt with via [Tarjan's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan's_strongly_connected_components_algorithm). Within each strongly connected component, strings may just be listed in arbitrary order and still satisfy the requirement, it seems.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: There are quite a few ways to do a topo-sort. The simple way is simply a depth-first-search (though "simple" doesn't necessarily imply efficient).

Comment: @JerryCoffin `There are quite a few ways to do a topo-sort.` Yes, but few of them can tolerate cycles.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: *None* of them can tolerate cycles (or at least none of them can succeed on a graph that contains cycles). Topological sorting is only possible on a DAG--any cycle makes a topo-sort impossible.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: however, so-called [robust topological sorting](http://www.logarithmic.net/pfh/blog/01208083168) can in fact tolerate cycles, essentially by treating each [strongly connected component](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component) as one big indivisible "vertex".

Comment: @JerryCoffin: nope, Tarjan doesn't help - you are not guaranteed to be able to arrange vertices within a strongly connected component in the right order. I think what one needs to do is find a spanning tree or forest, then topo-sort that.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Upon still further consideration, it's only tangentially related to topological sort. It's really a problem of finding a Hamiltonian path. The only DAG that contains one is a straight chain, and then of course topological sort finds it. But there are many graphs with cycles that also contain a Hamiltonian path. The problem is underspecified, in that it's unclear what is considered the "right answer" when there's no Hamiltonian path. One possibility is a [minimum path cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_cover); topo sort doesn't find one.

Answer (score 2):

First, problem #2 can be reduced to problem #1. Replace each string with a string consisting of the first letter and the last letter, separated by space; e.g. `AEIOU` becomes `A U`. Then it's clear that solving problem #1 on these new strings will also give the solution to problem #2 on original strings.

Second, this is a problem of finding a [Hamiltonian path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem) in a directed graph. The graph in question consists of the input strings as vertices, with an edge drawn between every pair of vertices of the form `X Y` and `Y Z`.

The problem, as stated, is underspecified: it's not clear what is considered the right answer when the graph doesn't contain a Hamiltonian path. Your example has `Pamela Luisa` followed by `Pedro Luis`, which doesn't satisfy the requirement. One possible interpretation is that of finding a [minimum path cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_cover).

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a better approach than this, but I would start by going through all of the words and assigning them numbers 0 to n.
Then each line can be represented as an ordered pair of numbers.
Then if there are k lines, create a (k x k) matrix of bools.
In each spot put true if the second word in the pair for that column matches the first word in the pair for that row, and false otherwise.
At that point you should be able to implement a simple backtracking search to find some sequence of lines (x_0, x_1,...) such that matrix[x_i][x_{i+1}] = true for all i.
Hope that helps.
If you can solve the first problem, the second should be very similar.

Comment: In other words, build an [adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) representing the input graph, then find a [Hamiltonian path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem) in that graph. The latter part is much harder than the former - NP-hard, to be precise.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik precisely, but I thought I should describe exactly what that involved. Thanks for contributing the mathy side.

Comment: And in my defense, I didn't say the simple backtracking search would be _fast_. And in case anybody wants to nitpick about my statement that there's probably a better approach to an NP-hard problem, depending on the constraints he's given, there might be some clever trick to simplify the problem. And there are dynamic programming approaches that will usually perform better than a naive search.